# C++ move semantics behaving differently based on the function return type

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have two functions taking in an rvalue reference to a string and adding something to that string. The first function returns the modified string and the second one has return type void.

Calling the first function on a string results in the original string being emptied, which is what I expected. However, calling the second function on a string brings it to its modified state as if the function were taking an lvalue reference.

Can someone please explain what is going on here? Is the compiler (VC++ configured for ISO C++ 14) doing some sort of "optimisation"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string g(string&& s)
{
    s += " post g call";
    return s;
}

void f(string&& s)
{
    s += " post f call";
    
}

int main()
{
    string s1("starting string");
    string s2("starting string");

    auto s1a = g(move(s1));
    f(move(s2));

    cout << s1 << endl;
    cout << s1a << endl;
    cout << s2 << endl;

}
```

s1 is empty string at the end of this program and s2 is "starting string post f call". I expected s2 to be empty as well.

Comment: std::move doesn't move

Since you never moved s2 into anything else, it remains.   S1 gets moved into the returned string, so it's empty

Comment: @xaxxon If I write "g(move(s1));" instead of "auto s1a = g(move(s1));", I observe the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, moved-from strings are not guaranteed to be empty. They are left in a "valid but unspecified state" (see #8 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)).

---

Next: I believe MSVC is misbehaving. Both `s1` and `s2` should retain their original values. ([That's what GCC and Clang do.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJICspLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiXXgAdUCwuto9QxMzSx8/NTo7B2cjNw8eRWVMVQCGAmZiAiDjUwsklUjadMyCaKdXd09FDKyckPyFWrL7CriqngBKRVQDYmQOAHIpAGZ7ZEMsAGpxEZ11JuJMZiNZ7HEABgBBUfHJzBm5xftgNc2d7YM/USnaFcwFL2YBqab0Wdlt8%2BOb4Agf06SABsUiBr0653EAHZPlspvDXjMZLMACJIyRTcIEKbAKYsVisKSSD7nBFTJYEPq0V4kr5QlGQ7YAN1QeHQUyo/wIxBOoNB4MhMNJCIUSNkIzRRMxvmxVDxbEJkmJI1h0IZX229mxRmY9ggELpsLJANenAgRKapROr25vKVEJVwvhJoUknNSstWWtAKJDtV2zJzAMRFNzEOaL%2BRlQTMw/04nT9To5ECjMf%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%2B8rH4wT7F40gxMYfEpLPAQbtyhTjOU1T4A0rSAh0/SCHeCUjJakzsosqyLNsyKzMc5z6DwNyPK8ny%2Bj86iAtoILtrwmLpwiqKabiycrySu80oyrKcWQZApko/KMTKgCiEq6r8CF%2BrGuauQ2tfDquqqXrBuG0bT3Gm9JsUabZtHbpjxVwaRNVhdvq1g9BskZmJuN9ruhjYg/A0bggA%3D%3D%3D))

`s1` is copied, not moved.

Whenever you use the name of an rvalue reference (or any variable) as an expression, the resulting expression is an lvalue. Or, in other words, rvalue reference variables are treated as lvalues unless they are `std::move`d. (As an exception, local variables in some cases are [implicitly moved in `return` statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Non-mandatory_elision_of_copy.2Fmove_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29_operations), but it doesn't apply to function parameters.)

But even if you do this:

```
string g(string&& s)
{
    s += " post g call";
    return move(s);
}

void f(string&& s)
{
    move(s) += " post f call";
}
```

Only `s1` will be empty, and not `s2` (accoding to both GCC, Clang, and MSVC).

That's because `std::move` by itself doesn't move anything, it doesn't make the parameter empty. It merely changes the value category of the parameter to rvalue.

If you look at [`std::string::operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), there are no overloads that could benefit from the lhs being an rvalue and move from it (none of them are `&&`-qualified, i.e. they don't have `&&` after the parameter lists).

Comment: Reading from a moved-from variable is well-defined, *not* undefined. But since the value is (usually) *unspecified*, it does not make a whole lot of sense to use that value. There are no guarantees what the value is, so what can you do with it except overwrite it with a known value?

Comment: @j6t Yes, you're probably right. Removed the part about UB.

Answer (score 1):

`std::move()` itself is just a type-cast, nothing more.  An rvalue reference is still a reference, and it is the receiver's responsibility to actually move the referenced data as needed. But neither  function is moving the data, only modifying it.

However, the `g()` function is returning the modified string *by value*, and `main()` is assigning that returned string to a local variable. In older versions of C++, a temporary `std::string` would have be created by that return, making a copy of the returned string, and then that temporary would be assigned to the target variable as another copy. But in modern C++ versions, [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) optimizes away that temporary and the copies, allowing the target variable to be *directly* initialized with the returned (modified) string.

It is that final initialization that ends up performing an actual move (whether or not it should be a move or a copy in this case is a matter of compiler implementation), which would explain why the original input string (`s1`) ends up being emptied when moved into the target variable (`s1a`).

Comment: I believe `s1` must be copied, not moved. The "local variables are implicitly moved in `return`" doesn't apply to function parameters.

Comment: i believe std::strings moved out of are in an unspecified state -- and design choices may be made around SSO (small string optimizations)

Comment: Without copy elision, `s1` would be copied, then the resulting temporary would be moved. But even with copy elision, I think it must be copied once. Clang even warns about it: [`warning: local variable 's' will be copied despite being returned by name [-Wreturn-std-move]`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nzYv48).

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I created a dummy class with a move constructor and lots of couts and your explanation is consistent with what I see during debugging. This behaviour stays the same if I don't assign the output of call to g to s1a, which I am not sure if it is legal C++. So I guess the compiler doesn't care whether there is an assignment but the return statement on its own triggers the behaviour you described.

Comment: *"whether or not it should be a move or a copy in this case is a matter of compiler implementation"* Hmm, I'm not sure. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Non-mandatory_elision_of_copy.2Fmove_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29_operations) says that under certain conditions local variables are implicitly moved in `return`, but says that it doesn't apply to parameters.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat copy elision is an optimization, the compiler decides how to implement it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've looked through the standard and found [`[class.copy]/31.1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#31.1) (says copy elision is not permitted for function parameters) and [`[class.copy]/32`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#32) (explains the "implicit move in return", says it must happen more or less iff criteria for copy elision are met).